# Filter out tiles with incomplete data take

Tags: sentinel-2, copernicus

I am facing an optimisation issue when downloading images from sentinel-2 with the EOdag API. Since the satellite orbits does not match up with the MGRS tiles, some of the tiles I download have incomplete data take over the complete tile, meaning you get "black zones" around the edges. For my application I don't want these images. Does anyone know a smart way to filter out these images, preferably in the query process, so I don't have to download them and then deleting them?

[image: Example of unwanted image]

Comment: Would it work if you filtered the scenes based on whether your area of interest is completely within the scene's (non black-zoned) geometry (which is `EOProduct.geometry`)?